# Is it correct to say "you have been being stoned" to mean you are criticized very hard by many people?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

You say or write something that make others upset and they start to criticize you very hard.

This particularly often happens on a social network.

Say, you posted on Facebook saying that "**women should stay at home taking care of children and not going to work**". A lot of feminists felt upset  with your comment and they start to criticize you.

Just imagine that in the past, there was a man who said God was not real and the crowd **threw stones at him** when he was escorted on the street by the authority.

In Vietnamese we say "**you have been being stoned for that**" (translated literally).

Is it correct to say "**you have been being stoned**" to mean you are criticized very hard by many people?

**Note**: it must carry the meaning that "**a lot of people have been criticizing that person**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recognise that without very good context, especially since someone being stoned can mean someone being intoxicated (ok probably wrong word there) by marijuana.

However, I have heard someone being lynched or crucified for a comment along those lines.

Comment: Just imagine that in the past, there was a man who said God was not real and the crowd **threw stones at him** when he was escorted on the street by the authority.

Comment: @Tom I do understand what stoning someone means, it is just that it is not a saying that I have ever heard before in the context of being criticised online.  I would recommend going with something more familiar.

Answer (score 1):

We can't say *have been being* in English. Either you *have been* criticised/stoned in the past, or you *are being* criticised now.

Comment: I think we can say it, although it is rarely idiomatic. "Have been getting"+*past participle* would work (see http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport2/hi/football/teams/n/newcastle_united/7976412.stm for an example), although "have been"+ptp and "are being"+ptp are both more likely.

Answer (score 0):

**Crucify**:

> *informal* Criticize (someone) severely and unrelentingly. ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/crucify))

**Pillory**:

> Attack or ridicule publicly.  ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pillory))

"You have been being crucified/pilloried" is unlikely: it would work with "getting" instead of "being".

"Stoned" isn't a likely metaphor.  As Garden Elf rightly said, "stoned" often means "high on drugs".

Comment: It has to mean "a lot of people criticize her". So, when we say "I have been being crucified", does it mean that a lot of people are criticizing me or just one?

Comment: It could mean either.  If we were talking about a social-media pile-on then it would probably be obvious from the context that it was a lot of people criticising you.  On Lexico, most of the examples refer to collective attacks, at least six do so unambiguously and only two refer to individual attacks.